# My segmented control will not change from 0 to 1. Is the problem with the way I set up the control, or is it a problem with the if statements?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am adding a segmented control that can switch from female(0) to male(1). It is for a nutrition app, so it has a range for healthy amounts of sugar, which are different between males and females. It does a calculation that results in a value of 1, 2, or 3 (sugar value) there is a text field where the amount of sugar consumed is entered and a label that shows 1, 2, or 3. It works for female, but the sugar value for male is always the same as female. I don't know if the problem is with changing the segmented control, or with the if statements. I’m very new to this, so please be patient.

```
@IBOutlet weak var controller: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var sugarField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var calorieRatio = 1.0
var sugarValue = 1.0
var sugarValueM = 5.0

@IBAction func changeLb(_ sender: Any)
{

     let sugarFieldConv :Double = Double(sugarField.text!)!

if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    
                            
        if sugarFieldConv >= 16.8 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 1.0
        }
                         
                        
        if sugarFieldConv <= 8.3 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 3.0
        }
                            
        if sugarFieldConv > 8.3 * calorieRatio && sugarFieldConv < 16.8 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 2.0
        }

    else if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                    

        if sugarFieldConv >= 25 * calorieRatio { sugarValueM = 1.0
        }
                                                 
        if sugarFieldConv <= 12.5 * calorieRatio { sugarValueM = 3.0
        }
                                                    
        if sugarFieldConv > 12.5 * calorieRatio && sugarFieldConv < 25 * calorieRatio { sugarValueM = 2.0
        }
        }
    

   if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { label.text = "\( sugarValue )" }
   if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 { label.text = "\( sugarValueM )" }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include a curly bracket right before `else if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1`. And then your second but last curly bracket is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your code will always give one value as it's a let and no action taken or updated, it's not like a tableView, in tableView you can use tableView.reloadData() to update the values but here there is nothing to able to update with.

You can use it with buttons like the image: "Check the second solution using segmented"

[image]

by the code below:

```
var sugarFieldConv :Double = 0.0
    @IBOutlet weak var sugarField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    
    var calorieRatio = 1.0
    var sugarValue = 1.0
    var sugarValueM = 5.0
    
  
    @IBAction func maleActionbtn(_ sender: Any) {
        sugarFieldConv = Double(sugarField.text!)!

        if sugarFieldConv >= 16.8 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 1.0
       }
       
       
       else if sugarFieldConv <= 8.3 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 3.0
       }
       
      else if sugarFieldConv > 8.3 * calorieRatio && sugarFieldConv < 16.8 * calorieRatio {
       sugarValue = 2.0
       }
        label.text = "\( sugarValue )"

    }
    
    @IBAction func femaleActionbtn(_ sender: Any) {
        sugarFieldConv = Double(sugarField.text!)!
        if sugarFieldConv >= 25 * calorieRatio {
                sugarValueM = 1.0
        }
        
       else if sugarFieldConv <= 12.5 * calorieRatio {
            sugarValueM = 3.0
        }
        
       else if sugarFieldConv > 12.5 * calorieRatio && sugarFieldConv < 25 * calorieRatio {
            sugarValueM = 2.0
        }
        label.text = "\( sugarValueM )"


    }
}
```

Or you can use segmented but without using its action you will need a button instead but you still have and use your segmented like the image:

[image]

Code:

```
class SegmentedViewControllerII: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var controller: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var sugarField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    var calorieRatio = 1.0
    var sugarValue = 0.0
    var sugarValueM = 0.0
    var sugarFieldConv = 0.0
    
    @IBAction func changeLb(_ sender: Any)
    {
        
//
//        if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
//            label.text = "\( sugarValue )"
//
//        }
//        else if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
//            label.text = "\( sugarValueM )"
//
//        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonCalculate(_ sender: Any) {
        sugarFieldConv = Double(sugarField.text!)!
        
        if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            
            
            if sugarFieldConv >= 16.8 * calorieRatio {
                sugarValue = 1.0
                label.text = "\( sugarValue )"
            }
            
            
            else if sugarFieldConv <= 8.3 * calorieRatio {
                sugarValue = 3.0
                label.text = "\( sugarValue )"
            }
            
            else if sugarFieldConv > 8.3 * calorieRatio && sugarFieldConv < 16.8 * calorieRatio {
                sugarValue = 2.0
                label.text = "\( sugarValue )"
            }
                
                
            
            
            else if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                
                
                if sugarFieldConv >= 25 * calorieRatio {
                    sugarValueM = 1.0
                    label.text = "\( sugarValueM )"
                }
                
                else if sugarFieldConv <= 12.5 * calorieRatio {
                    sugarValueM = 3.0
                    label.text = "\( sugarValueM )"
                }
                
                else if sugarFieldConv > 12.5 * calorieRatio && sugarFieldConv < 25 * calorieRatio {
                    sugarValueM = 2.0
                    label.text = "\( sugarValueM )"
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}
```